# VSE rerendering whole video for just a simple effect

Tags: video-sequence-editor

sometimes I add very simple effects to videos (files are already in video format). For example I just add simple fade in / fade out effect in the beginning / end of the video like in the image below:

[image]

However this rerenders large portions of the video which haven't been edited at all hence adding these simple effects can be very time consuming. The frames between the gamma cross strips actually don't need to be rerendered. 
So my question: Is there an approach to skip these frames in order to save some time? (As I said the file is already in a video format, no image sequences availabe)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: No, I don't think it is, not with blender at least, as far as I know. If you had separate image sequences you could just render the fade in and out parts, but you'd still have to compose it all into one video file afterwards,so no real way around it. That's the thing about video files, You always have to compose the final cut into a self contained strip from beginning to end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rendering out the timeline, so everything in the timeline is rewritten, therefore you cannot just do the new bits.

However you could render the portions with effects as seperate clips then use an external app to join them to the original. A program like ffmpeg will do this appending function, but I don't recall if you can alter the start and end time of the un-effected clip in the middle. Anyway ffmpeg is a faster tool but at this point you may as well use Blender too render it all as a single piece.

Comment: Or use Avidemux for such video joins